# Visualize negative/positive data using levelplot in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, levelplot

I need your insights on how to visualize/map data that span negative and positive values. I have 6 rasters which have been stacked together (`s`) and will subsequently be plotted via the `levelplot` function in R. Below are the `max` and `min` values for each `raster`.

```
39.2887, 53.09207  (min, max) # r1
-32.4956, -27.25534  (min, max)# r2   
-14.37683, -11.37742  (min, max)# r3    
9.512934, 13.60197  (min, max)# r4    
-4.993901, -1.851784  (min, max)# r5    
-8.190711, -5.104764  (min, max)# r6
```

At the moment, I am able to produce my map via:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(colorRamp)
    s <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
    themes2 <- colorRampPalette(c("darkred", "red3", "orange", "yellow", "lightskyblue", "royalblue3", "darkblue"))(19)
    myat =unique(seq(floor(min(s)) ,ceiling(max(s)),length.out=20))
    myat=round(myat,digits = 0)#     
    #themes <- rasterTheme(region=rev(brewer.pal(11,'RdYlBu')))
    myColorkey <- list(at=myat,space = "right",labels=list(cex=1,at=myat))

    if (dev.cur() == 1) x11(width=18,height=18)

    levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)),col.regions=themes2,  
              margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,at =unique(seq(floor(min(s)) ,ceiling(max(s)),length.out=20)),
              par.strip.text=list(cex=0),colorkey=myColorkey,scales=list(alternating=F))
```

NOTE: I need a single colorkey common to all rasters.

Problem: for rasters with smaller ranges, the variation amongst cells is poorly conveyed - the information on the map is not well visualized. How can I visualize such data using `levelplot` with this large overall range?

You can generate 6 rasters with values within the ranges shown above to give me further clues.

Thanks for your help!
The colorkey does not need to be red to blue. Something like ["The Default Rainbow Palette"](http://iges.org/grads/gadoc/colorcontrol.html) would do.

[image]"

I need a single, shared colorkey for all of these rasters. At the moment, rasters with smaller cell ranges show very LITTLE variation.

Comment: Do the six rasters represent the same variable, or are they for six different variables?

Comment: @Pascal they represent the same variable. Assume you have temperature data for a site and you want to compare this data over different scenarios and future time windows. You will need a single colorkey for such comparisons. That is the issue I am trying to solve as explained above.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your post. In that case, you can follow Oscar's advices.

Comment: What does this mean: "rasters with smaller vs larger values get suppressed"? Do you mean that for rasters with a relatively small range, the variation in cell value is difficult to see because the colours for that small section of the ramp are so similar?

Comment: @jbaums, exactly! rasters with large ranges show more variation unlike those with smaller ranges (colors do not vary as much). I have uploaded a sample map to illustrate...

Comment: Your problem boils down to the fact that there is much greater between-raster variation than within-raster variation. This is honestly conveyed by the rendering of colour. What is the story you are trying to tell with this plot?

Comment: @jbaums the plot shows three columns corresponding to three scenarios. The letters (a,b,c,d) indicate the seasons of the year (winter,spring,summer,autumn). In (a) for example, row1 indicates the period 2011-2054 while row2 is the period 2055-2098. By using a single colorkey, I can compare the spatial structure of precipitation changes under the 3 scenarios, two periods, 4 seasons.  As you explained before, most rasters get very small color variations due to the small ranges...@Oscar suggested I rescale the data plot((s-cellStats(s,"min"))/(cellStats(s,"max")-cellStats(s,"min"))). Pls help.

Comment: If you're interested in the magnitude of change at each cell, between the two time periods, then you can subtract the 2011-2054 grids from the 2055-2098 grids. You'll then have half as many rasters, and will lose information about what the values have changed _from_, but I imagine this will deal with your concerns about colour. I can't see too many other ways around it.

Comment: @jbaums thanks for the insights. I will try all suggestions. Someone also advised that I make use of coloramps such as that in Fig.1. of this document http://www.geosci-model-dev.net/5/245/2012/gmd-5-245-2012.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have two choices:

1. Use a different key for each graph.
2. Rescale the data to create a common scale.

Because you need a single colorkey you should rescale the data. Although [this document](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf) is about time series, it gives good advices about this issue.