# What is the best way to plot more than one raster with large between-raster variation in R?

Tags: r, maps, raster, r-raster

I have been trying to develop a better solution to visualize my data using R. However, my efforts have not been fruitful so far.

Assume you have 6 rasters ( the data is for a single variable measured at different times) where within-raster variation is not so large but between-raster variation is larger.

You need a single colorbar for the 6 rasters. What I am after is to display the 6 rasters, still be able to see the within and between raster variation, and create a single color key with break labels.

[One suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28779086/964866) is to rescale the data and create a common scale. Something like:

```
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)
s = stack(r1,...,r6)
s = (s-cellStats(s,"min"))/(cellStats(s,"max")-cellStats(s,"min"))
```

After rescaling the data, the between raster variation reduces and looks better.

Besides, how can I produce a colorbar legend which uses `zlim=(min(s),max(s))`, `s` beeing the unscaled data?

Large reproducible example:

[r1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1aiypvszmpdh6k/r1.txt?dl=0)

[r2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/58la5neih7o9wty/r2.txt?dl=0)

[r3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn010qb24w8xe3v/r3.txt?dl=0)

[r4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8un2rhqsydt206/r4.txt?dl=0)

[r5](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb9ljatusoeb06w/r5.txt?dl=0)

[r6](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lbmq8csk8ii2gr/r6.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Please, could you post a reproducible example?

Comment: If you need to define a custom colorkey, use the `colorkey` argument as explained in [this FAQ](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#sec-1).

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Oscar. For sure I am able to define the breaks and do pretty much work using raster and rasterVis thanks to your contributions. How to visualize the kind of data we often encounter in climate research remains a dilemma. If this the issue I am raising here is resolved then one can make better use of the mapping tools in R. I have edited the question to include a large reproducible example via dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far:

```
library(hydroTSM)

x.tsZ<-as.numeric(precip[,1])# gives r1 points for interpolation etc

names(x.tsZ)<-EbroPPgisZ$ID

x.idw <- interpo(x.ts= x.tsZ, x.gis=EbroPPgisZ, 
                    X="EAST_ED50", Y="NORTH_ED50", sname="ID", bname="CHE_BASIN_NAME",
                    type= "cells",p4s= projjj,
                    subcatchments= EbroCatchmentsCHE,
                    cell.size= 18000, col.nintv=100,col.at=at,
                    ColorRamp= "PCPAnomaly2",  
                    main= "IDW Precipitation on the Ebro")


## Removing unncesary field
x.idw@data["var1.var"]  <- NULL

# Setting the projection of the interpolated object (ED50 Z30N)
proj4string(x.idw) <- projjj

#library(raster)
x.idw.r <- raster(x.idw)

# Defining the LatLong spatial reference
wgs84.p4s <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs")

# Re-projecting the from ED Z30N to LatLong WGS84.
x.idw.r.ll <- projectRaster(from=x.idw.r, crs=wgs84.p4s@projargs, method="ngb")

# Saving the raster file into a GeoTiff
#####                                                                     #####
##### ATENTION : The following line will WRITE A FILE into your hard disk #####
#####                                                                     #####
writeRaster(x.idw.r.ll, file="myfile1.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)

# display raster alongside boundaries
ras = raster("myfile1.tif")

cr <- crop(ras, extent(Prairie.Boundaries), snap="out") 
fr <- rasterize(Prairie.Boundaries, cr) 
r1  <- mask(x=cr, mask=fr)
# repeat the above for r2...26


    myat =unique(seq(10.87775,  16.74664,length.out=col.nintv))#col.nintv=45
    myat2=round(myat,digits = 1)# 
    a=unique(myat2)
    a[seq(0, length(a), 5)]
    myat1=c(11.3, 11.8, 12.3, 12.8, 13.3, 13.8, 14.3, 14.8, 15.3, 15.8, 16.3)# output of "a" defines where to place labels

    themes2 <- themes<- colorRampPalette(c("sienna4", "peachpuff","orange", "yellow", "lightskyblue1", "royalblue3", "darkblue"))#(length(myat)-1)

    myColorkey <- list(at=myat,space = "bottom",labels=list(axis.line = list(col = NA),cex=1,font=1,at=myat1,rot=0),height=1,width=1)#also control lengend with
    #coordinates(SITES...TTEST) <- ~x+y
    #detach ggplot2 before running this

    if (dev.cur() == 1) x11(width=10,height=6)
    s <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
    levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)),col.regions=themes2,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,contour=F,
              par.strip.text=list(cex=0),scales=list(x=list(draw=FALSE),y=list(draw=FALSE)),colorkey=myColorkey,at=myat)+# add points to map

      layer(sp.points(SITES...TTEST, pch=ifelse(SITES...TTEST$Precip_JJA1 < 0.05, 3, 1), cex=.4, col=138), rows=1,columns=1) +layer(sp.polygons(watersheds,lwd=0.5))+# add polygons to map
      layer(sp.points(SITES...TTEST, pch=ifelse(SITES...TTEST$Precip_JJA2 < 0.05, 3, 1), cex=.4, col=138), rows=2,columns = 1)+
      layer(sp.points(SITES...TTEST, pch=ifelse(SITES...TTEST$Precip_JJA3 < 0.05, 3, 1), cex=.4, col=138), rows=1,columns = 2)+
      layer(sp.points(SITES...TTEST, pch=ifelse(SITES...TTEST$Precip_JJA4 < 0.05, 3, 1), cex=.4, col=138), rows=2,columns = 2)+
      layer(sp.points(SITES...TTEST, pch=ifelse(SITES...TTEST$Precip_JJA5 < 0.05, 3, 1), cex=.4, col=138), rows=1,columns = 3)+
      layer(sp.points(SITES...TTEST, pch=ifelse(SITES...TTEST$Precip_JJA6 < 0.05, 3, 1), cex=.4, col=138), rows=2,columns = 3)
```

[image]